# SPServices CopyIntoItemsLocal, works on original site, but not in site created from its template

Tags: 2013, spservices, template

```
        mySPServices().SPServices({
            operation: "CopyIntoItemsLocal",
            async: false,
            SourceUrl:srcurl ,
            DestinationUrls: [desturl], 
            completefunc: function(xData, Status)
            {           

            }
            });
```

**The Problem:**

The copy does not take place. No document arrives at the destination url.

The xml comes back saying the SPService call was successful, however it returns the error message "Value does not fall within the expected range."

**Debugging Attempts and Background Information:**

The problematic site was created from the saved template of the original site.

This is a SharePoint 2013 Site.

Both the source and the desination urls are valid. While debugging I printed them to the console and placed them in the browser and they both worked.

I have full permssions on the site.

What within the enviroment of the site created from the template could be preventing the copy?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was, that the target list had a field that the orginal list did not have. It was like finding a needle in a haystack, however once this field was deleted from the list the script worked beautifully.